# Ruby on Rails - Next Day creates a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications

I want to create an application using Ruby,where a user can plan his next day, so when he is logged-in he should be able to plan the following day and at midnight the next day should be automatically created.

But I don't know how to do this.

Any suggestions?

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by drawing out your schema on some paper, with a pencil.  Think about all the real life things you want to model, and how they relate to each other.  You should understand the object-relational model before doing this.  Your thought process will be something like

*Ok, so the user wants to plan something.  Let's call the "thing" an Event.  So, draw a box for event.  Now, what are the characteristics of an Event?  It starts at a particular time*, and it ends at a particular time, and it has a name.  So, it will need to have start_time, end_time and name fields.*

*We've also got users, so we'll need a User box.  A user has_many events, so draw an arrow from Event to User to show that the Event belongs_to the user.*

There's your basic schema.  Note how you don't have a Day box.  That's because you don't need a Day model.  All an event has to do is store when it starts and ends.  When you come to DISPLAY the data, you can organise it by days if you want, but that's just a view onto the data.

*when i say "Time" here, i mean an instance of the Time class, which holds the date *and* time of day: it's a specific point in time, not just a time of day like "3 o'clock" or something.  So a time would be like "2016-02-15 16:19:09" for example (how it's stored in my database)